# How do I crawl my own website?

Tags: asp-classic

I've inherited an old Classic ASP website to modify.  Although not requested up-front, I'd like to delete a bunch of the old "orphaned" pages.

For some reason, The old developer decided to create muliple instances of the file instead of using source control (eg. `index-t.asp, index-feb09.asp, index-menutest.asp`).

I'm wondering if anyone knows of a program or website, that can crawl my own site for me?  It probably needs to be able to crawl public site, since there are lots of include files.  Also, some of the urls are relative and some are absolute.

Comment: This has parallels with Garbage Collection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My favorite tool is [Xenu](http://home.snafu.de/tilman/xenulink.html).

Comment: Do you konw if this software has a recursive feature?  or a limit?

Comment: If it has a limit I have not hit it. I have used this on sites with over 10,000 pages. Also note that unlike W3C's tool (which is fine as far as it goes), this tool has the ability to detect orphan pages if you allow it FTP access to your site.

Finally unlike some of the other techniques suggested, Xenu makes real requests to the site so it works just fine with dynamically generated webpages.

Here is the Winipedia page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xenu%27s_Link_Sleuth.

Comment: requires Microsoft Windows 95/98/ME/NT/2000/XP/Vista/7/8/10, WININET.DLL

Answer (score 1):

There's also the W3C link checker: http://validator.w3.org/checklink

Comment: This has a limit of 150 pages when i crawl recursively

Answer (score 0):

You should never let a once-valid URL go stale.  Bad web developer!  No biscuit!!

Comment: Is that true? There's a lot of overhead in maintaining dead link warnings, and when I update my browser favorites, I'd rather have them 404/403 than 200 with a "this page is gone" message.

Answer (score -1):

You should consider:

1. Putting the entire existing site into source control, then
2. Delete the extra pages and see who complains

Comment: It's already been added to source control, that was my first task.  Now I'm trying to delete the extra pages, but, I want to make sure I don't delete pages that are needed.